# how do I stop timer from showing up in my other levels?

Tags: android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I made a game with 3 levels, easy,normal, and hard.

easy has 300 seconds before the timeup activity shows up,
normal has 600 seconds ,
hard has 900 seconds

for example, I chose easy but I lose so I went back to choose what level I would take next. I chose normal but the timer page for easy shows up.

how do I stop the TIMER from popping up in my other levels.

I am missing something

activity for level:

```
public class EasyAct extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    int score =0;
    TriviaQuizHelper1 triviaQuizHelper1;
    TriviaQuestion1 currentQuestion;
    List<TriviaQuestion1> list;
    int qid = 0;
    int level = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_easy);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviTimer);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(300 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                tv2.setText("Timer:" + l / 1000 + " " + "sec");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                tv2.setText("TIME OUT");
                Intent intent = new Intent(EasyAct.this, timeup.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
        triviaQuizHelper1 = new TriviaQuizHelper1(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = triviaQuizHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
        triviaQuizHelper1.allQuestion1();
        list = triviaQuizHelper1.getAllQuestion();
        currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
        view();
    }

    public void view() {
        tv1.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        b1.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOpta());
        b2.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptb());
        b3.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptc());
        b4.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptd());
        tv3.setText("Level:"+level);
        tv4.setText("Score:"+score);
    }


    public void ButtonA(View view) {

        if (b1.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
            score+=300;
            if(qid<19){
                qid++;
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                view();
            }else{
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("xscore",score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void ButtonB(View view) {
        if (b2.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
            score+=300;
            if(qid<19){
                qid++;
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                view();
            }else{
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("xscore",score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void ButtonC(View view) {
        if (b3.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
            score+=300;
            if(qid<19){
                qid++;
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                view();
            }else{
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("xscore",score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void ButtonD(View view) {
        if (b4.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
            score+=300;
            if(qid<19){
                qid++;
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                view();
            }else{
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        else {
            Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putInt("xscore",score);
            intent.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();

    }
}
```

Comment: i only see 300 seconds being passed to the timer, do your other activitys have different amounts hardcoded? I would guess you just need to declare the timer as a global variable for each class, then you can call the timer.stop() method when you lose or start over

Comment: where will I type the timer.stop() in the code I posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the timer before you switch activities. If you don't, the new activity will be displayed on the screen, but the timer from the old activity can still fire. To do this explicitly, you'll need a reference to the timer that you can access *outside* of your `onCreate()` method. A simple way to do this is by declaring your CountDownTimer as a class field. Then you can access the variable anywhere inside this class.

```
public class EasyAct extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
    int score =0;
    TriviaQuizHelper1 triviaQuizHelper1;
    TriviaQuestion1 currentQuestion;
    List<TriviaQuestion1> list;
    // declaring CountDownTimer as a class field
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    int qid = 0;
    int level = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_easy);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviTimer);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        // initializing the CountDownTimer instance
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(300 * 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                tv2.setText("Timer:" + l / 1000 + " " + "sec");
            }
```

Then you can call `countDownTimer.stop()` before you call `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take countDownTimer as a global variable and cancel it as and when a new activity is started as follows :

```
public class EasyAct extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
        TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
        int score =0;
        TriviaQuizHelper1 triviaQuizHelper1;
        TriviaQuestion1 currentQuestion;
        List<TriviaQuestion1> list;
        int qid = 0;
        int level = 1;
        private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // declare as a global variable

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.act_easy);

            tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
            tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviTimer);
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
            b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
            b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
            b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
            tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level);
            tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
            // initialize the timer
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(300 * 1000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {
                    tv2.setText("Timer:" + l / 1000 + " " + "sec");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    tv2.setText("TIME OUT");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(EasyAct.this, timeup.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            };
            countDownTimer.start();
            triviaQuizHelper1 = new TriviaQuizHelper1(this);
            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = triviaQuizHelper1.getWritableDatabase();
            triviaQuizHelper1.allQuestion1();
            list = triviaQuizHelper1.getAllQuestion();
            currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
            view();
        }

        public void view() {
            tv1.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            b1.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOpta());
            b2.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptb());
            b3.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptc());
            b4.setText(" "+currentQuestion.getOptd());
            tv3.setText("Level:"+level);
            tv4.setText("Score:"+score);
        }


        public void ButtonA(View view) {

            if (b1.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
                score+=300;
                if(qid<19){
                    qid++;
                    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                    view();
                }else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else {
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putInt("xscore",score);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        public void ButtonB(View view) {
            if (b2.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
                score+=300;
                if(qid<19){
                    qid++;
                    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                    view();
                }else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else {
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putInt("xscore",score);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        public void ButtonC(View view) {
            if (b3.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
                score+=300;
                if(qid<19){
                    qid++;
                    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                    view();
                }else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else {
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putInt("xscore",score);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        public void ButtonD(View view) {
            if (b4.getText().toString().equals(" "+currentQuestion.getAnswer())){
                score+=300;
                if(qid<19){
                    qid++;
                    currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                    view();
                }else{
                    Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultWon.class);
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else {
                Intent intent=new Intent(EasyAct.this,ResultPlayAgain.class);
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putInt("xscore",score);
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            a.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            a.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(a);
            finish();
        }
    }
```